# rewriteRule to make url user friendly

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two rules. 
first one to allow request without .php extension
and the second one rewrite all request start with /account/(.*)$ to  /account.php?action=$1.

what's wrong with the account rule? and why does it miss with resources path?

These are my rules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?account/(.*)$ /account.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^account/(images/.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^account/(.*)$ /account.php?action=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Make sure for your images, js and css files paths are absolute i.e. they start with a slash or `http://`

Comment: I cannot change the images path

Comment: What is the current URL of your image?

Comment: That's not complete URL. Is it `http://example.com/images/image.png` or something else? Also tell me what is your DOCUMENT_ROOT and where is account.php located in DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: my document root is /home/ddd/public_html. the images are under /home/ddd/public_html/images. The account.php is under the DOCUMENT_ROOT